# Activiti: count method on nativeTaskQuery

Tags: java, activiti

I've creating a NativeTaskQuery:

```
NativeTaskQuery nativeCountQuery = taskService.createNativeTaskQuery().sql("SELECT task.* FROM BLABLA...");
```

*listPage(0,10)* method returns correctly a list paginated of the results

But *count()* method throws an exception:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 27
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.selectOne(DbSqlSession.java:458)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntityManager.findTaskCountByNativeQuery(TaskEntityManager.java:185)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.NativeTaskQueryImpl.executeCount(NativeTaskQueryImpl.java:36)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractNativeQuery.execute(AbstractNativeQuery.java:143)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
```

Is that method bugged? How i can get a count of the result for my NativeTaskQuery?

Comment: The system expects exactly 1 result you ask for many results. Maybe you should call a different method?

Comment: I've tried with "SELECT COUNT(\*)" instead of "SELECT task.\*" and now seems work perfectly.

But i still don't understand why i've to make a duplicate query for a count...

Comment: The result of count is a single result. The tasks are a list i.e. many results ;)

Comment: Yeah i know, i was using count() method like on TaskQuery, but obviously it cannot change dinamically the select clause on a NativeTaskQuery :'(